# Bootstrap - elements in div separates into 2 lines when width changes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The elements in div separates into two lines of elements when `width < 720px`. I think this has to do with the fact that I'm using Bootstrap's grid system.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
```

This line of code uses `navbar-expand-md`, which means that the max container width is 720px according to the Bootstrap 4.2 documentation. But I can't find an way to fix this issue.

How can I fix this?

Here's the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/17g6uqvt/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS Property `inline-block` for `#search-box`

```
#search-box {
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    height: 1.8rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Change some javascript function

```
var COLLAPSE_WIDTH = 768;

function init_navbar () {
    $('.nav-link').on( {
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        }
    });

    window.isCollapsed = true;
    $('.btn-search').on('click', function () {
        if (window.windowSize > COLLAPSE_WIDTH) {
            $('#search-box').toggleClass('hidden');
            $('.navbar-nav').toggleClass('hidden');
        }
        window.isCollapsed = !isCollapsed
    });
}
function check_width() {
    window.windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < COLLAPSE_WIDTH) {
        $('#search-box').removeClass('hidden');
        //$('#search-btn').addClass('hidden');
        $('.navbar-nav').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.nav-link').addClass('collapsed');


    }
    if (windowSize > COLLAPSE_WIDTH) {
        $('#search-box').addClass('hidden');
        //$('#search-btn').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.navbar-nav').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.nav-link').removeClass('collapsed');

    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    check_width();
    $(window).resize(check_width);
    init_navbar();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/3h9eawz7/1/